# Is this a monad (in Java)?

Tags: java, monads

Before I go around claiming I've nailed it, I wanted to ask. Don't hold back, please, I'd like to experience any criticism here first.

Since Java lacks the flexibility the dynamic languages have in passing arbitrary arguments, I compensated by bundling all possible inputs into one class (People), which forms the input space. The functions map that to the output space (Friends) with the help of the monad.

I'm not trying to solve the general case, just come up with an example to see if I understand the design pattern.

The monad (if it is such) enforces these rules: once an invitation is rejected, or there is an error, there is no further processing.

Sorry for the length. It is Java after all. I've taken some shortcuts with convention to save space.

Is this actually an example of a monad? (Encapsulated in the Friends class)

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        People people0 = new People("Bob", "Fred");
        Friends friends0 = Friends.pipeline(people0, ToFromFunction.INVITE, ToFromFunction.ACCEPT);
        System.err.println(friends0);

        People people1 = new People("Bob", "Jenny");
        Friends friends1 = Friends.pipeline(people1, ToFromFunction.INVITE, ToFromFunction.ACCEPT);
        System.err.println(friends1);

        People people2 = new People("Bob", "Fred");
        Friends friends2 = Friends.pipeline(people2, ToFromFunction.INVITE, ToFromFunction.BLOCK);
        System.err.println(friends2);
    }
}

/** this is the space of all inputs */
public class People {
    public People(String from, String to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String from;
    public String to;
}

/** this is the output space, and the monad (?) */
public class Friends {

    public boolean friends = false;
    public boolean rejected = false;
    public String errors = "";

    public static Friends unit(People from) {
        return new Friends();
    }

    public Friends bind(ToFromFunction f, People from) {
        if (! errors.isEmpty()) {
            // we have errors; skip the rest
            return this;
        }

        if (rejected) {
            // No means no
            return this;
        }

        return f.act(from, this);
    }

    public static Friends pipeline(People from, ToFromFunction... functions) {
        Friends result = Friends.unit(from);
        for (ToFromFunction f : functions) {
            result = result.bind(f, from);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

/** functions from People to Friends */
public interface ToFromFunction {

    Friends act(People from, Friends to);

    ToFromFunction INVITE = new ToFromFunction() {
        public Friends act(People from, Friends to) {
            // Jenny has blocked Bob
            if ("Jenny".equals(from.to) && "Bob".equals(from.from)) {
                to.errors = "Jenny blocked Bob";
            }
            return to;
        }
    };

    ToFromFunction ACCEPT = new ToFromFunction() {
        public Friends act(People from, Friends to) {
            // Good to go!
            to.friends = true;
            return to;
        }
    };

    ToFromFunction BLOCK = new ToFromFunction() {
        public Friends act(People from, Friends to) {
            to.friends = false;
            to.rejected = true;
            return to;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What're you getting at @BrianGordon?  Those are the on-topic guidelines for Programmers, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, I'm saying that it would be an appropriate question for Programmers. It's not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: "Is this actually an example of a monad?" -- the original post kind of trailed off at the end. Edited to clarify that, thank you!

Comment: I believe you are close in terms of functionality however since Java does not allow to pass functions (does not treat functions as first class citizens), you need to (pre)wrap all functions in your `ToFunctionInterface` which seriously limits composability of functions and the binding of functions together via the `pipeline` is not super elegant. But as you said, this is Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monads are Types, that implement two functions with a fixed signature: unit and bind.

In Haskell notation:

```
unit :: a -> m a

bind :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

`unit` wraps an object from type `a` into an `m` of type `a`. The type of `a` must be arbitrary.  Implementation of `bind` can be anything (but it must satisfy the monadic laws).

Let's try to convert your example into Haskell syntax:

People is just a tuple:

```
type People = (String, String)
```

The type of Friends is a tripel of two booleans and a String.

If we use these types, than your Friends.unit method is something like this:

```
unit_friends :: People -> Friends
unit_friends _ = (false, false)
```

That means, `unit_friends` is discarding is parameter and just returning a new instance of `Friends`. This is the wrong type signature for `unit`. Instead, unit should have this type signature:

```
unit_friends :: a -> Friends a
```

In Java, this should look something similar to:

```
public static Friends<T> unit(T from) {
    // return something of type Friends<T>
}
```

Your `bind` function takes a function of type `ToFromFunction` and an object of type `People` and returns something of type `Friends`:

```
bind_friends :: ToFromFunction -> People -> Friends
```

Let's replace `ToFromFunction` with

```
type ToFromFunction = People -> Friends -> Friends
```

because that's the type signature of `act`.

```
bind_friends :: (People -> Friends -> Friends) -> People -> Friends
```

Let's flip the arguments of bind_friends, because the lambda function should be the second parameter:

```
bind_friends :: People -> (People -> Friends -> Friends) -> Friends
```

But it shoud have this type signature:

```
bind_friends :: Friends a -> (a -> Friends b) -> Friends b
```

Your types of unit and bind don't match that of a real monad, but it is kind of close.

Let's forget for a moment, that we need an arbitrary type a. The first parameter of `bind_friends` must be of type `Friends`, not of type `People`, because `bind` should lift `ToFromFunction` to the `Friends` monad.

Comment: So that's even more abstract than I thought, and I can see how the strong typing in Java is an impediment. But I like the flexibility of the almost-monad; I'm interested to see how a closer version works out. Thanks again for taking a look at that.

Comment: FYI I added your input and took another crack http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/229135/is-this-a-monad-in-java-part-2 ... I think I got the signatures right this time.